# How to use jgit clone method with SSL dissabled?

Tags: java, jgit

EDITED

I am cloning git project using jgit library, and I need to clone this as ssh disabled. So I tried the Following method

`Git result = Git.init().setDirectory(localPath).call();`

`StoredConfig config = result.getRepository().getConfig();`
`config.setBoolean( "http", null, "sslVerify", false );`
`config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", gitUrl);`
`config.save();`

`result.fetch().setRemote("origin").call();`

But still, I am getting

`org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://XXXX:XXX/root/XXXX.git: cannot open git-upload-pack`

Is there a better way to clone git project with SSL disabled?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to save the config

```
Git git = new Git(localRepository);
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", "http://github.com/user/repo");
config.setBoolean( "http", null, "sslVerify", false );
config.save();
```

More info on this here : -

https://newbedev.com/turn-ssl-verification-off-for-jgit-clone-command

Comment: I tried that method as well, but still, get this error "TransportException occur while cloning the project, cannot open git-upload-pack"

Comment: It is not a problem with your code, such an error occurs only if there is a problem in the Git Remote you have and also I have seen this error if there is a network proxy issue or firewall issue as well. I the easiest way to confirm that would be to clone some thing from github and try .